# Как сделать переход на другую страницу в android?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-material

У меня есть Material Drawer который сделан автоматически в Android Studio. Как мне сделать, что бы когда пользователь нажимал на определённую кнопку, его переносило на другое окно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [ссылка на код MainActivity](http://goo.gl/beJM0N)

Comment: Если вы используете шаблон из Android Studio, то там вроде как уже реализованы переходы при нажатиях на пункты меню. В чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: Здравствуйте, вот мой код MainActivity https://goo.gl/beJM0N .
Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на определённую кнопку в  NavigationView запускалось нужное активити

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

       //code
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PutClassName.class);
       startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Повесьте слушатель нажатий на NavigationView.
2. В нём, в зависимости от id нажатого элемента запустите нужную активити/отобразите фрагмент.
3. Закройте drawer